# Can a list of websites be considered a corpus for a particular category?

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, corpus

I am trying to build my own corpus for particular categories such as Engineering, Business, Math, Science and etc... This will be for automatic web page categorization. Let's say I manually collect 100 websites that are related to Math. Can these 100 websites be considered a corpus for Math?

Another related question. How does this differentiate from a lexicon wherein instead of a list of websites it shows a list of words with weights such as 0 or 1 to particular categories? Example would be a sentiment lexicon with words that has weights for positive and negative. But instead of positive and negative, categories such as Math, Science are used.

Comment: A corpus is just an ensemble of data. Then your 100 websites of math could be considered as a subsample of your corpus, corresponding to the label "math" (in case you're doing supervised learning).

Comment: @debzsud Ohh now I see. What would the difference be then from a lexicon? I have edited the question.

Comment: I hope by collectiong you mean the content of these sites, not just urls?
It will be hard to categorize sites only by url.
If it's content, then this task is not different from having documents with text.

Comment: You shouldn't ask several question in one post. You should definitely get some courses on machine learning on general to understand your problem. I'll make an answer to put some words on what I guess you're trying to work.

Comment: @CrazyElf Yes, I am actually referring to the contents.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to make some web page categorization, then the problem you're facing is a **supervised learning** problem. The data you get are web pages, so I guess you actually extract their content as text. You work with **textual input data**. Since you want to categorize them, each of your input data has one or more corresponding **labels**, which are the **outputs** you want to predict. You have multiple label so you want to do **multi-label classification**

To tackle this problem, since most machine learning algorithms work with numerical vector, you need to transform your **corpus** of texts into vectors (or into one matrix). To do so, you can use the **[bag of word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)** technique which first build a **dictionary** or **lexicon** and then count the occurrences of each word of the dictionary in each text. Actually, you can transform your output label in the same way, attributing an index of you output vector for each category.

The final **pipeline** would be something like this:

[input_text] --bag_of_word--> [input_vector] --prediction--> [output_vector] --label_matchnig--> [labels]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Can I use TF-IDF in building the dictionary or lexicon instead of just counting the occurences?

Comment: You can try TF-IDF, sometimes it's useful, sometimes is not.

Comment: Yes, tf-idf is one possible next step to represent your texts as vectors. You also have LSA, LDA, word embedding, and more complex deep learning models.